# How to Use the Output of Observable.ToEvent()?

Tags: system.reactive

how can I effectively use the output of Observable.ToEvent()?  I was hoping that I could route this back into a standard .NET event (for example, adding a TripleClick event handler to a Windows form as an academic exercise).

However, the method outputs a System.Reactive IEventSource, and I'm not sure how that translates back into the world of standard .NET events.  Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The `IEventSource` has an event called `OnNext`, this event doesn't follow the normal pattern or `object sender, EventArgs e`, instead being an `Action<Unit>`.

As an example:

```
var source = new Subject<Unit>();
source.ToEvent().OnNext += unit => Console.Writeline("hello");
source.OnNext(Unit.Default);

outputs

"hello"
```